# Polynomial roots in C

Tags: linear-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

I have trouble understanding how to prove the following theorem.
Let $f$ be a polynomial and let be $c_1,c_2,\dots,c_n$ all different roots of $f$. Then there is an element $c$ in the field so that
$$f=c(x-c_1)(x-c_2)\dots(x-c_n)$$
I understand that for the theorem to be true it is needed that the field is algebraically closed, if so there is missing information in the factorization of the polynomial, such as the conjugated roots of every complex root. 
I hope I have explained myself rather well. If someone could explain why this happens I would be very grateful.

Comment: $f=c(x-c_1)(x-c_2)\dots(x-c_n)$ is the standard form for a polynomial, so it's basically the factor theorem. In other words, it says that any polynomial can be factored. The use of the variable names starting with $c$ suggests they mean the complex field, which results in this being a true statement.

Comment: "I understand that for the theorem to be true it is needed that the field is algebraically closed": not really. Meaning: as it is stated, the theorem is false regardless of $\Bbb K=\overline{\Bbb K}$ because it is not specified that $n=\deg f$. With the assumption "$n=\deg f$", I would read it: "Let $\Bbb K$ be a field, $f\in\Bbb K[x],\ \deg f=n$ and $c_1,\cdots, c_n\in\Bbb K$ be distinct roots of $f$. Then there is $c\in\Bbb K$ et cetera..." This is true regardless of $\Bbb K$ being algebraically closed, due to a special case of the remainder theorem.

Comment: This statement is not correct as written.  For instance, if $f(x)=x^2$, then you would just have $c_1=0$ and no other different roots, and the statement would claim $f(x)=cx$ for some $c$.  You need to allow the roots to be "repeated" potentially.